# How to deploy Elastic beanstalk in azure pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to deploy Elastic beanstalk in my azure pipelines -

Please find the below Screenshot -
[Elastic beanstalk task in azure release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5loRh.png)

```
----------------------Error logs --------------------------------------
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6521278Z Task         : AWS Beanstalk Deployment
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6521576Z Description  : Build task to upload a new application version to an Elastic Beanstalk in AWS.
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6521853Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6522042Z Author       : Mark Buggermann
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6523563Z Help         : [More Information](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?spirit21.AwsBeanstalkReleaseExtension)
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6524834Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6614707Z ##[warning]Task 'AwsBeanstalkRelease' (1.0.0) is using deprecated task execution handler. The task should use the supported task-lib: https://aka.ms/tasklib
2020-07-06T02:00:53.6629328Z Preparing task execution handler.
2020-07-06T02:00:57.1505265Z Executing the powershell script: D:\a\_tasks\AwsBeanstalkRelease_506e537c-a122-40ae-928d-13e78628f6ff\1.0.0\beanstalk_deployment.ps1
2020-07-06T02:00:57.3802165Z Loading PowerShell module for AWS
2020-07-06T02:00:57.3927527Z ##[error]System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module 'AWSPowerShell' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7435795Z ##[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Set-AwsCredentials' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7437450Z    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7437876Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7438468Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7438899Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7719683Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 2 errors.
2020-07-06T02:00:57.7727364Z ##[section]Finishing: Release new Beanstalk application
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official [AWS toolkit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/welcome.html) task like below. Also the error says "The specified module 'AWSPowerShell' was not loaded" which means your build agent does not have "[AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-getting-set-up-windows.html)" installed.

[image]